# Remove tab highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, fortran, vim-syntax-highlighting

When I write .f90 or .f file I have the problem that vim always highlight the first number of empty columns with red [See figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8DJS.png). I have tried to use :noh but did not work. If I use "set list" they disappear but then a lots of symbols appear.
[My vimrc file can be see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvovx.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab isn't part of the Fortran character set, so a properly formatted Fortran source file shouldn't contain tabs. You might want to configure vim to replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You can use set expandtabs in your vimrc, that will produce spaces instead of tabs.